# Load GUI from separate file

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer

I have been making an gui for my work, and everything is working perfect with Windows form.

The problem is now that i want to save all the Design and form region into another file. and just load it. Reason: so we can change the design of the GUI if needed and just edit the GUI.ps1 file.

I had the idea that it is just the Main.ps1 that need to be executed. when we need to use the Program.
Any help would be nice.

```
Main.ps1
 |_GUI.ps1
 |_Functions-files.ps1
```

Gui.ps1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$FMmain = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$TCmain = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
.....
$FMmain.showdialog()
```

Comment: You need to use [**dot sourcing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) for that: `. .\GUI.ps1` so that your object variables will be in the same scope as your caller (`Main.ps1`).

Comment: Thank you, That did the job. 

Just had to call the Showdialog on the Main.ps1